# Conditionally use #warning or #pragma message or nothing

Tags: c-preprocessor

I have a code which uses `#warning` a lot to signal compile time branches to the user. The code has a lot of configuration option, therefore it is not really clear which bits of the code are actually taken into the compilation.

Once you have chosen the configuration options, those warnings really clutter the output. So I would like to be able to disable them. The easiest way would be wrapping each of those warnings into an `#ifdef ... #else` construct. But if I was to touch that code again, I need to go through the whole codebase again.

So instead I want to abstract this a bit. However, I am stuck trying to define a macro that calls `#warning` or `#pragma message`. The following compiles but does not do the right thing:

```
#ifdef EMIT_WARNINGS
#define WARNING(s) _Pragma("message(\"Hi\")")
#else
#define WARNING(s)
#endif

WARNING("How can I print this?")
```

All my attempts of putting `s` into there have failed. Once I do `_Pragma("message(\"" s "\")")`, I get that `_Pragma` expects a single parenthesised string.

Is there anything I can do to abstract this nicely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All my attempts of putting s into there have failed. Once I do _Pragma("message(\"" s "\")"), I get that _Pragma expects a single parenthesised string.

`_Pragma(S)` has an effect equivalent to `#pragma X`, where X is the *unstringified* form of S.  Going backwards, that means that to get the effect of `#pragma X` in a `_Pragma` call, you simply need to *stringify* X.

The fact that part of X is itself a string is misleading you... don't think of these as pieces you're assembling, but rather as a whole.  Rather than trying to stringify `s` and put it inside `"message(\""` and `"\")"`, just stringify `message(s)` itself as a whole, like this:

```
#ifdef EMIT_WARNINGS
#define WARNING_I(s) _Pragma(#s)
#define WARNING(s) WARNING_I(message(s))
#else
#define WARNING(s)
#endif
WARNING("How can I print this?")
```

So when warnings are enabled, `WARNING("How can I print this?")` expands to `WARNING_I(message("How can I print this"))`.  That argument to `WARNING_I` is itself what you would put on a pragma line; it is your `X`.  The definition of `WARNING_I` then stringifies that, making the correct `S` for `_Pragma`.

Answer (score 0):

From https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.3.0/cpp/Diagnostics.html#Diagnostics

> Neither ‘#error’ nor ‘#warning’ macro-expands its argument. Internal whitespace sequences are each replaced with a single space. The line must consist of complete tokens. It is wisest to make the argument of these directives be a single string constant; this avoids problems with apostrophes and the like.